# in php trying to use post man to get request from database and provide a response

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I tried running but only got the else message no message found when i var_dump sender and receiver got null i also have this public $enableCrsfValidation.I want to get the receiver sender and user id if there are there response to be succesfull.

```
public function actionGive()
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        try{
            
            $request = Yii::$app->request;
            $sender=$request->post('sender');
            $receiver=$request->post('receiver');
            $userId = $request->post('user_id');
           // if ($sender === null || $receiver === null || $userId === null) {
              //  throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid input parameters. Make sure sender, receiver, and user_id are provided.');
            

            // Fetch message from the database
            $message = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
            SELECT message
            FROM inbox
            WHERE sender = :sender AND receiver = :receiver AND user_id = :user_id
            LIMIT 1
        ')
        ->bindValue(':receiver', $receiver)
        ->bindValue(':sender', $sender)
        ->bindValue(':user_id', $userId)
        ->queryScalar();

        if (!empty($message)) {
            return ['status' => 'ok', 'description' => "sucess"];
        } else {
            return ['status' => 'error', 'description' => 'No data found for the provided name.'];
        }
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       //  Handle exceptions
        return ['status' => 'error', 'description' => $e->getMessage()];
     }
    }
```

I tried running but only got the else message no message found when i var_dump sender and receiver got null i also have this public